# Skip empty cell after the specified word using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm use Xpath to extract data from Excel files. I use the below Xpath code to get the values under a specific word.

Code:

```
//tr[position() > count(//tr[contains(.,'Tariff')]/preceding-sibling::tr)+1]/td[position() = count(//tr/td[contains(.,'Tariff')]/preceding-sibling::td)+1]
```

This is working but I came across some Excels that adds an empty `<td>` right after word "Tariff". Which actually mess up the end result. Below is part of the Excel which is converted to HTML source I work with.

Code:

```
            <tr style="height:22px;">
               <td style="padding:0 2px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:bottom;">22</td>
               <td data-cell="A22" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:thin solid #000000;font-weight:700;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" rowspan="2">Tariff </td>
               <td data-cell="B22" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:thin solid #000000;font-weight:700;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" rowspan="2">Description</td>
               <td data-cell="C22" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:thin solid #000000;font-weight:700;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" rowspan="2">Country of origin</td>
               <td data-cell="D22" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:thin solid #000000;font-weight:700;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" rowspan="2">Quantity</td>
               <td data-cell="E22" style="border-color:#000;border-bottom:thin solid #000000;font-weight:700;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" rowspan="2">Amount DKK</td>
               <td data-cell="F22" style="mso-number-format:'0';border-color:#000;border-bottom:thin solid #000000;font-weight:700;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;" rowspan="2">Net weight kg</td>
               <td data-cell="G22" style="border-color:#000;font-size:13px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:26px;">
               <td style="padding:0 2px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:bottom;">23</td>
               <td data-cell="G23" style="border-color:#000;font-size:13px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:20px;">
               <td style="padding:0 2px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:bottom;">24</td>
               <td data-cell="A24" style="border-color:#000;border-top:thin solid #000000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">42022290</td>
               <td data-cell="B24" style="border-color:#000;border-top:thin solid #000000;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">BAG</td>
               <td data-cell="C24" style="border-color:#000;border-top:thin solid #000000;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">CN</td>
               <td data-cell="D24" style="border-color:#000;border-top:thin solid #000000;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">2</td>
               <td data-cell="E24" style="mso-number-format:'#,##0.00';border-color:#000;border-top:thin solid #000000;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">147,06</td>
               <td data-cell="F24" style="mso-number-format:'0.000';border-color:#000;border-top:thin solid #000000;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">0,558</td>
               <td data-cell="G24" style="border-color:#000;font-size:13px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:20px;">
               <td style="padding:0 2px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:bottom;">25</td>
               <td data-cell="A25" style="border-color:#000;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">61043900</td>
               <td data-cell="B25" style="border-color:#000;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">JACKET</td>
               <td data-cell="C25" style="border-color:#000;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">CN</td>
               <td data-cell="D25" style="border-color:#000;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">1</td>
               <td data-cell="E25" style="mso-number-format:'#,##0.00';border-color:#000;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">146,14</td>
               <td data-cell="F25" style="mso-number-format:'0.000';border-color:#000;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;">0,364</td>
               <td data-cell="G25" style="border-color:#000;font-size:13px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
            </tr>
```

The `<tr>` I want skip is this one,

Code:

```
            <tr style="height:26px;">
               <td style="padding:0 2px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:bottom;">23</td>
               <td data-cell="G23" style="border-color:#000;font-size:13px;padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;"></td>
            </tr>
```

I tried using `//tr[contains(.,'Tariff') and (text()!='')]/preceding-sibling::tr)+1` and the I tried `not(contains(.,''))` but that also didn't work. Can some one help me to figure this out.

Comment: Can you describe in plain text which elements you want to select? Which version of XPath do you use? And as you have also used the tag for XSLT, do you need a pure XPath expression or can you also use XSLT with variables, grouping etc.?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I want to skip or not select the empty node right under or following the word "Tariff". I use both V1 and 2. I want a pure XPath expression I made mistake by adding the XSLT tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is a bit complicated. You want to get value under the specific word "Traffic".
If you really want to keep your XPath, add a condition at the end of it :

```
//tr[position() > count(//tr[contains(.,'Tariff')]/preceding-sibling::tr)+1]/td[position() = count(//tr/td[contains(.,'Tariff')]/preceding-sibling::td)+1][contains(@data-cell,"A")]
```

But shorter XPath also work :

```
//td[contains(.,"Tariff")]/following::td[contains(@data-cell,"A")]
```

If you need something without having to specify the name of the column ("A" for Traffic), then use :

```
//td[contains(.,"Tariff")]/following::td[contains(@data-cell,substring(//td[contains(.,"Tariff")]/@data-cell,1,1))]
```

Comment: `@data-cell` can you tell me what does this do please.

Comment: `td[contains(@data-cell,"A")]` will look for a td element with a @data-cell attribute containing the letter "A". The last XPath expression will search a td element regarding 2 conditions : to follow a td element containing the word "Tariff", and to have the same @data-cell attribute (i.e. the same column letter) of this preceding td element.